# Static navbar in reactJS Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to make static navbar which does not follow user on sroll.Is there any way to do it in
react-bootstrap?

```
<Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
  <Nav className="mr-auto">
    <Button className={'bootstrapProfile'} variant="outline-info">
      <Link key={uuidv4()} to={`/profile/${user.id}`}>
        My Profile
      </Link>{' '}
    </Button>
    <Button
      className={'bootstrapNewTopic'}
      variant="outline-info"
      onClick={() => {
        history.push('/posts');
      }}
    >
      New Topic
    </Button>
  </Nav>
  <Button variant="outline-info" onClick={() => LogOut()}>
    Log Out
  </Button>
</Navbar>
```

I tried to give it classname `fixed-top` but it did not work.
Please help

Comment: It should be a question related to CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using react-bootstrap component Navbar. If that is correct instead of giving class in the component you can try.

```
<Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" fixed="top">
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a class say `fixed-top-nav`. And use `position: sticky` property to stick it on the top. Add this class to your `navbar`

```
.fixed-top-nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the navbar to follow the user as they scroll, you don't need to add any special props to the Navbar.

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-bootstrap-navbar-ps9m1?file=/src/App.js)